# Not able to compile MLY file using Dune

Tags: ocaml, ocamllex, ocamlyacc

I am writing my first Ocamllex and Ocamlyacc program by following [this](https://youtu.be/yySh6WLCn7A) tutorial

My dune file looks like

```
(executable
 (public_name Calculator)
 (name main))
(ocamllex lexer)
(ocamlyacc parser)
```

My lexer.mll file is

```
{
  open Parser
}

rule read = parse
  | eof { EOF }
```

And parser.mly file is

```
%token EOF

%start <unit> prog

%%

prog:
  | EOF { () }
  ;
```

My main.ml file is

```
type expr = unit 

(** [parse s] parses string [s] into an AST. *)
let parse (s: string): expr = 
  let lexbuf = Lexing.from_string s in 
  let ast = Parser.prog Lexer.read lexbuf in 
  ast

(** [interp s] interprets [s] by Lexing and parsing it, 
    evaluating it, and converting the result into string *)
let interp (s: string) : string = 
  failwith "unimplemented"
```

When I say `dune build` I just get an error

```
File "bin/parser.mly", line 3: syntax error
%start <unit> prog
```

However the tutorial I am following (linked above) the same code compiles and runs. and it shows how to parse and empty string. I don't know much about this error because its not tell me what the syntax error is. I have written the code exactly as shown in the video.

Comment: If you want to use the `%start <unit> prog` syntax you should use menhir and not ocamlyacc like it's written in the description of the video you linked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ocamlyacc doesn’t have that `%start <type> symbol` syntax. You should separately specify the type using `%type`:

```
%type <unit> prog
%start prog
```